# Centre of mass based TSP solution (2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, traveling-salesman

I updated the code to a working state. [My previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/291288/centre-of-mass-based-tsp-solution). Even if this code working I wonder if I can write this code in a more efficient way. Maybe less for loops Etc.

```
from tkinter import *
import math
import random

class city:
    def __init__(self,coordinates,name):
        self.coordinates = coordinates
        self.name = name


path = []
origin_list=[]
removed_cities=[]
total_distance_base=[]
distances_to_current=[]
distances_to_centre=[]
distances_to_centre_step_two=[]
distances_to_centre_complete=[]
total_distance=[]
total_distance_complete=[]
last_list=[]
fake_origin_list = []

def city_creator():
    sum_of_coordinates_x = 0
    sum_of_coordinates_y = 0
    for i in range(50):
        randone = random.randint(0, 700)
        randtwo = random.randint(0, 700)
        a = city((randone,randtwo),i)
        origin_list.append(a)
        sum_of_coordinates_x+=randone
        sum_of_coordinates_y+=randtwo
    return [sum_of_coordinates_x,sum_of_coordinates_y]


sum_all = city_creator()
sum_x = sum_all[0]
sum_y = sum_all[1]

def distances_to_centre_of_mass(x,y,lst):
    distances_to_centre_step_two.clear()
    distances_to_centre.clear()
    distances_to_centre_complete.clear()
    avg_x = int(x//len(lst))
    avg_y = int(y//len(lst))
    for city in lst:
        distances_to_centre.append([int(math.sqrt((avg_x-city.coordinates[0])**2
                                   +(avg_y-city.coordinates[1])**2)),city.name])
    for dist in distances_to_centre:
        distances_to_centre_step_two.append(dist[0])
    distances_to_centre_step_two.sort()
    for final in distances_to_centre_step_two:
        for i in distances_to_centre:
            if final == i[0] and (i in distances_to_centre_complete)==False:
                distances_to_centre_complete.append(i)
    return distances_to_centre_complete

fcity = distances_to_centre_of_mass(sum_x,sum_y,origin_list)

def path_creator():
    while len(origin_list) != 0:
        sumx = 0
        sumy = 0
        for d in origin_list:
            sumx += d.coordinates[0]
            sumy += d.coordinates[1]
        distances_to_centre_of_mass(sumx, sumy, origin_list)

        last_list.clear()
        total_distance_base.clear()
        total_distance.clear()
        last_list.clear()
        distances_to_current.clear()
        for i in origin_list:
            if len(origin_list) == 50:
                distances_to_current.append(
                    [int(math.sqrt((fcity[-1][0] - i.coordinates[0]) ** 2 +
                                   (fcity[-1][1] - i.coordinates[1]) ** 2)), i.name]
                )
            else:
                distances_to_current.append(
                    [int(math.sqrt((removed_cities[-1].coordinates[0]-i.coordinates[0])**2+
                        (removed_cities[-1].coordinates[1]-i.coordinates[1])**2)),i.name]
                )
        for a in distances_to_current:
            for b in distances_to_centre_complete:
                if a[1] == b[1]:
                    total_distance.append([5*a[0]+2*b[0],a[1]])
                    total_distance_base.append(5*a[0]+2*b[0])
        total_distance_base.sort()
        for a in total_distance_base:
            for b in total_distance:
                if a == b[0] and (b in path)==False:
                    print(b)
                    path.append(b)
                    for c in origin_list:
                        print(c.name,b)
                        if c.name == b[1]:
                            origin_list.remove(c)
                            removed_cities.append(c)
                            break
            break

path_creator()
print(path)
print(len(path))
print(len(removed_cities))

window=Tk()
window.config(bg='White')
window.title('Hello Python')
window.geometry("1000x1000+10+20")
canvas = Canvas(width = 800, height = 900, bg = "white")
canvas.pack(pady = 5)

total_road = 0

for a in path:
    for b in removed_cities:
        if a[1] == b.name and (b in fake_origin_list) == False:
            fake_origin_list.append(b)
print(len(fake_origin_list))
for i in fake_origin_list:
    canvas.create_oval(i.coordinates[0]-3,i.coordinates[1]-3,i.coordinates[0]+3,i.coordinates[1]+3, fill="Black")
for i in range(len(fake_origin_list)):
    if i == len(fake_origin_list)-1:
        total_road += math.sqrt((fake_origin_list[i].coordinates[0]-fake_origin_list[0].coordinates[0])**2 + (fake_origin_list[i].coordinates[1] - fake_origin_list[0].coordinates[1])**2)
        canvas.create_line(fake_origin_list[i].coordinates[0], fake_origin_list[i].coordinates[1], fake_origin_list[0].coordinates[0],fake_origin_list[0].coordinates[1], width=2, fill='Blue')
    else:
        total_road += math.sqrt((fake_origin_list[i].coordinates[0]-fake_origin_list[i+1].coordinates[0])**2 + (fake_origin_list[i].coordinates[1] - fake_origin_list[i+1].coordinates[1])**2)
        canvas.create_line(fake_origin_list[i].coordinates[0],fake_origin_list[i].coordinates[1],fake_origin_list[i+1].coordinates[0],fake_origin_list[i+1].coordinates[1],width=2,fill='Blue')
Label(window, text= total_road).place(x=400,y=3)
window.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: A couple of different approaches come to mind that may make this faster: 1. Using OR tools for the formulation. For instance [here](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/examples/tsp_py.html) is gurobipy example code for solving the TSP "efficiently". 2. If you are not interested in an exact solution, but one that is good, it should be noted you are solving the Euclidean version of the problem which has a [well known polynomial time approximation scheme](https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs468-06-winter/Papers/arora-tsp.pdf).